# Area of all triangles involved in a big triangle.

Tags: triangles, puzzle, area

I have a big triangle made up of several small triangle as depicted in picture given below.

[image]

Suppose, there is one generic triangle of this shape which is formed by joining points arranged in **n** rows. For example, shape given in above picture is obtained by joining points arranged in **5** rows.

I want to find sum of area of all triangles present in this picture, infact in a generic picture of same shape.

Manually, I can find it by summing area of unit triangles, area of triangles formed by 4 unit triangles, area of triangles formed by 9 unit triangles ... area of triangles formed by **(n-1)^2** unit triangles ..etc.

How can I derive a generic formula to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you figure out how many unit triangles there are (with a formula)? What about $k$-sided triangles?

Comment: If points are arranged in n rows( n - 1 triangle in each side), then there will be (n - 1) ^2 unit triangles. @shardulc

Comment: If you can derive similar formulae for $k$-sided triangles, then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

The lower left unit triangle of a triangle with sides parallel to the enclosing triangles and  with side length $k$ can lie anywhere in the lower left triangle of side length $n-k$, so there are $\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}2$ such triangles.

The top side of a triangle with the opposite orientation and with side length $k$ can be anywhere from $k$ to $n-1-k$ rows below the upper tip of the enclosing triangle, and if it's $l$ rows below the tip it has $l-k+1$ options for its horizontal position, for a total of

$$
\sum_{l=k}^{n-1-k}(l-k+1)=\frac{(n+1-2k)(n-2k)}2\;.
$$

A triangle with side length $k$ contains $k^2$ unit triangles. Thus the total area in units of unit triangles is (with $r=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor$)

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}2k^2+\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{(n+1-2k)(n-2k)}2k^2\\
=\frac1{120}(n-1)n(2n^3+7n^2+7n+2)\\+\frac1{60}r(r+1)(24r^3-3(10n-7)r^2+(10n^2-20n-11)r+5n^2+5n-4)\;.
$$